# How to get a returned value in asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How would i get the returned value in `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`

my code -

```py
async def getUser(id:int):
  return await d.fetch_user(id) # it returns what i want ....

def get_or_create_eventloop():
  try:
    return asyncio.get_event_loop()
  except RuntimeError as ex:
    if "There is no current event loop in thread" in str(ex):
      loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
      asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
      return asyncio.get_event_loop()


@flask_app.route("/getData", methods=["POST"])
def getData():
  print("GOT")
  print(str(server.request.data))
  data = json.loads(server.request.data)
  id = data["id"]
  data_n = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(getUser(int(id)), loop=get_or_create_eventloop())
  print(data_n.result()) # here nothing prints out
  name = data_n.name
  id = data_n.id
  p = data_n.u
  data = {"name":name, "id":id, "p": p}
  print(data)
  return str(data)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing prints out"?  The Python print statement has to print something, even if it's just a blank line.  What about the other print statement four lines later?

Comment: The code doesnt even reach till that line. (Prints nothing ...) @PaulCornelius

Comment: I just see `GOT` then `b'{"id" : 123456789}'`, and then the console and flask app become silent ...

Comment: Okay, that's a much different problem than "nothing prints out."  Your program is deadlocked, most likely because the call to data_n.result() does not return.  Is your program actually multi-threaded?  This code won't work unless a second thread performs the call to fetch_user().  When that function returns, the run_coroutine_threadsafe logic will set the result into `data_n`.  The object `data_n` is a concurrent.futures.Future, which is not an awaitable.  The call to data_n.result() blocks the main thread until the result is available.

Comment: Yes, the program is multi-threaded @PaulCornelius , the flask app is running in a different thread. And are you saying that i should put `d.fetch_user` directly in `run_corountine_threadsafe` instead of a function ???

Comment: No, that's not what I said.  `run_coroutine_threadsafe` takes a coroutine as its first argument, and I don't know if d.fetch_user(id) is in fact a coroutine.  My question is, is the loop object that you are passing to `run_coroutine_threadsafe` actually a running loop in a second thread?  If it's not, you will get a deadlock.  Perhaps you can present the code for your function `get_or_create_event_loop`.

Comment: Ok @PaulCornelius now I pasted the code of function get_or_create_eventloop in the question ...

Comment: There's your problem.  That function will always return the event loop of the current thread, creating a new one if necessary.  The event loop you need here is the event loop in the OTHER thread.  The way your code is written, everything is trying to happen in the same thread.  Your function call to result() blocks the current thread until the data is available.  Another thread is needed to unblock it.   You may be running Flask in another thread, but you are running the function getUser in the same thread as the call to run_coroutine_threadsafe.

Comment: So, how would i get (or create) an event loop of the other thread ????